# Loading external file via $.get often not returning response, even that response code is 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, caching, knockout.js

I have a website running on Azure. In there, I'm playing with Knockout.JS components and custom loaders. I've used a very simple example from KO documentation found here:

(A component loader that loads external files using custom code)
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#custom-component-loader

```js
// loader helper
var templateFromUrlLoader = {
  loadTemplate: function(name, templateConfig, callback) {
    if (templateConfig.url) {
      var today = new Date();
      var fullUrl = templateConfig.url + "?v=" + today.getTime();
      $.get(fullUrl, function(markupString) {
        ko.components.defaultLoader.loadTemplate(name, markupString, callback);
      });
    } else {
      callback(null);
    }
  }
};



// component is registered
ko.components.register('postcode-lookup', {
  viewModel: function() {
    // component js
  },
  template: {
    url: 'https://www.purplebricks.com/content/lib/component-postcode-lookup/dist/component/templates/postcode-lookup.html'
  }
});




ko.components.loaders.unshift(templateFromUrlLoader);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Now, locally, everything works perfectly, each time a page gets refreshed, the component template is fetched:

[image: XHR status]

and the preview of the response is here:

[image: XHR preview]

The problem arises when the page is deployed to staging/live production. It will work for every person just fine the first time, but as soon as you refresh the page, the probability of template returning blank response is very very high = almost 90%. It is clearly cached, the response code becomes 304 not modified, but the response is blank. I've tried adding a query string that adds a timestamp to it - it made almost 0 difference. Now I have a 200 status code, but the time of the request goes into pending and seems to last forever:

[image]

[image]

It almost feels like Azure is caching this incorrectly, perhaps DNS issues?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be down to an incorrectly set gzip header, try adding the following to your route config to prevent ASP.NET MVC from processing the static content:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
```